# Can Dauntless Bodyguard give a land indestructible if it was animated previously?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have a [Shambling Vent](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shambling%20Vent). I animate it, then play [Dauntless Bodyguard](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dauntless%20Bodyguard) targeting it. At the end of turn, Shambling Vent returns to being a land. Next turn, opponent uses a land destruction spell on Shambling Vent. Can I sacrifice Dauntless Bodyguard to give Shambling Vent indestructible, thereby countering the land destruction spell?

Relevant text of Dauntless Bodyguard:

> Sacrifice Dauntless Bodyguard: The chosen creature gains indestructible until end of turn.

The question hinges on whether this ability still works given that Shambling Vent isn't a creature at the time Dauntless Bodyguard is sacrificed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Kaya The Inexorable with Luxior, Giada's gift](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/57563/kaya-the-inexorable-with-luxior-giadas-gift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can. As long as the first ability of Dauntless Bodyguard resolved at a time the land was also a creature, it will track that permanent.

> 700.7 If an ability of an object uses a phrase such as “this [something]” to identify an object, where [something] is a characteristic, it is referring to that particular object, even if it isn’t the appropriate characteristic at the time.

Comment: You're right about the rules but I think your conclusion is wrong. In the OP's scenario, Shambling Vent has already stopped being a creature when the ability is activated.

Comment: In the example provided along with rule 700.7, a delayed triggered ability that references "that creature" is created, and it works even if that object is no longer a creature by the time the ability triggers. The instance in question is about an activated ability instead of a delayed trigger, but otherwise it's essentially the same issue. The important thing is that the referenced object is defined earlier, and the later ability still refers to the same object.

Comment: @Andrew How does rule 700.7 not apply here? The characteristic of "creature" has been removed, but the object was previously chosen.